# Unexpected output in dividing two numbers

Tags: java

Why is this code giving `0.0` as answer?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float ans = (480/1080);
    System.out.println(ans);
}
```

Comment: you need to cast with (float).

Answer (score 3):

You are dividing two integers, so the result is integer. 480/1000 < 1 and is therefore truncated to 0. Then the result is cast to float to be stored in the float variable.

To divide the numbers as floats, cast one of them:

```
float ans = ((float)480/1080);
```

Comment: Or just `float ans = 480f/1080;` -- appending `f` to a number literal marks it as a float.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Here both numbers will be float so You'll get float value..

```
 float ans = ((float)480/(float)1080);
            System.out.println(ans);
```

**Output:**
    0.44444445